# How to set default min and max column width in ag-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid library for advanced data grid.

In ag-grid library, I can define "minWidth" and "maxWidth" attributes in "columnDefs" to set minimum and maximum width for particular column.

But is there any option to set default min and max width for each column to set re-sizing boundaries for columns?

Answer (score 0):

Have a single function in the scope to define column widths and heights.

```
$scope.commonWidth = function() {
      return 50 + calcDynWidth();    //Dummy function
}


$scope.gridOptions = {
   columnDefs: [
      {headerName: 'Name', minWidth: $scope.commonWidth()}
   ]
}
```

Comment: Through columnDef, I have to define minWidth and maxWidth attributes for each column. I am looking for a way where I can configure and set min/max width which will be applicable for all the columns.

Comment: I believe this way you can do it in one place. The other easiest way is to change the source.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
<ag-grid-angular
      [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"



public defaultColDef: ColDef = {
    wrapHeaderText: true,
    autoHeaderHeight: true,
    minWidth: 100,
    floatingFilterComponent: 'myCustomFilter',
    filter: 'myCustomFilter',
    type: ['defaultColumn'],
    sortable: true,
  };
```

The minWith property is the key